# Changing primary key generation with ManyToManyMapping

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to find a work-around for the EclipseLink bug bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=344448.

The issue is that EclipseLink chooses a primary key made of entity ID + hashmap value ID for each entry of the HashMap. I would like to modify to have the primary key of entity ID + hashmap key ID instead. This is not only an issue with the primary key constraint but also with the SQL statements generated by EclipseLink, eg delete, update, etc...

So... I saw there is a way to customise this behaviour using a Customiser and by grabbing the ManyToManyMapping of the hashmap field and modifying whatever is needed. I can't find much documentation on this so I am sort of trying out things... but so far no success.

```
public class ConfigureValuesFilter implements DescriptorCustomizer {

public void customize(ClassDescriptor descriptor) throws Exception {
    ManyToManyMapping mapping = (ManyToManyMapping) descriptor
            .getMappingForAttributeName("values");


    // various attempts
}
```

I tried setting the primary key with mapping.setTargetRelationKeyFieldName ("value_KEY"); and the setTargetKeyFieldNames (why does it need both?) but this resulted in an array index out of bound error with the table (from the key) I want to use not available in the descriptor, see below.

```
Exception Description: The table [CASEVALUE] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(testdb.EULADocument --> [DatabaseTable(EULADOCUMENT)])
```

Then I tried changing the delete query statement with setDeleteSQLString, but I am stuck on how to pass the parameter values

```
mapping.setDeleteSQLString("DELETE FROM LICENSE_EULADOCUMENT WHERE ((values_KEY = #VALUES_KEY) AND (License_ID = #LICENSE_ID))");
```

says it could not find the VALUES_KEY so sets it to NULL...

What is the recommended way to modify the behaviour?

Comment: I don't under stand your entry in bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=344448 -what exactly are you trying to workaround?  The bug itself is that someone wants the PrimaryKey constraint generated in the DB for schema generation done differently - a simple solution since you can just generate the script and modify it directly. I would not suggest runtime behaviour change be made for this bug.

Comment: Sure, I can change the primary key constraint in the DB BUT I still have the problem of the updates on the DB. If I update the hashmap, the delete statement generated to remove the updated row uses the combination of entity ID + value ID to select the row to delete, instead of entity ID + key ID.

Comment: I wouldn't file a new bug that indicates the functionality you want implemented - seems reasonable

Comment: You would or you wouldn't? they don't seem particularly responsive... I moved on after a few days of trying to fiddle with customisers and else, refactored my model :(